# How to display 2 column Dropdown List ASP classic

Tags: html, sql-server, asp-classic, dhtml, html-select

I am currently transforming systems that was made in MS Access and I am reprogramming all web based using ASP classic. I'm in a little snag and I really looked all over the web for this for the passed 2 days and no luck.

What I am trying to accomplish is a drop down list that as 3 simple column like the current systems in Access so say I am looking for the follow output in the HTML select list.

Choose a company

```
walmart         25 street Montreal 
crazy man       36 bad street Laval
bad company     36 ethos street app 32 Quebec 
hello world     36 apples Toronto
```

This output comes from a SQL Server database.

I tried the following: counting how much characters are in the company name (say..20 chars), then I want to add equal spaces to the company name so say (100 chars).

In this case I will would take the amount (100-20) and add this the the company name then take the name of the company and join it to the address and town.

Each time I go through the loop I redo the calculation.

This is all done in asp classic here is the code

```
<select id="search_Comp" name="search_Comp">
<option value="0">---</option>
<%
'loop
while not RS.EOF

'check if the company name is smaller than 100 characters
if len(RS("Comp_Name")) < 100 then

 'calculation of the padding
  whiteSpaceSize = 100 - len(RS("Comp_Name"))

end if 

'create the spaces need
nameCompSP = space(whiteSpaceSize)

'add the spaces to the company name  
nameComp = trim(RS("Comp_Name")) & nameCompSP

'replace for spaces for html output
NnameComp = replace(nameComp," ","&nbsp;")


%>
<option value="<%= trim(RS("Comp_ID"))%>"><%=NnameComp %><%= trim(RS("Comp_CAdd1"))%></option>
<%
RS.MOVENEXT
wend 
%>
</select>
```

this outputs the spaces but they still don't line up !

I tried with SQL too but didn't work

```
-- here is the query example --
SELECT 
    Comp_Name + SPACE (100 – len(Comp_Name)) + Comp_CAdd1 AS Comp_Name 
FROM 
    company
/****address will always be 100 char way from the first char of Company, the space in between padded with spaces ***/
```

but still outputs the columns with spaces but don't line up...

Can someone help me with this? I am not finding anything and no info in google and forums - let me know please really appreciated...

K3v_n

Comment: Guess this just impossible :( still looking for a answer !

Answer (score 0):

Because the default font used is proportional, they'll never line up. You need to use a monospaced font.

in your stylesheet, use:

```
select {
    font-family:courier;
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Comment: i Tried this but it only effects the main input of the select drop down. the results from the drop down list... what i am trying to accomplish is to align the company name and address in to separate columns.. to help add the user in selecting and viewing this list

Comment: You many want to consider a script-based alternative: http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/10-jquery-form-select-boxes/

Comment: i didn't see any two column dropdown list in the link ?

Comment: No, but you can put your own HTML in the drop-down and use CSS to make two columns using some of these tools.

Comment: I tried putting the following and firefox doesn't catch the css and ignore it.. 'code'<option value='1'><span class='lblNameComp'>walmart</span> 666 hell street</option> 'code' i added a css to this with both margin and padding and no results